# Kibana; group by a field but show another one on the chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I want to group some value (sold items for example) by country name in Kibana. Problem is if I use a Term aggregation then it shows "United States" as two buckets "United" and "States".
the "country_name" is an analyzed field which is some thing I can not change.
I am currently grouping by a country_code field but on the chart it shows as 3 letters code that some times is not easy to recognize which country is that.
I would like to keep grouping by country_code but show the country_name instead ! any thoughts on that ?

Comment: `the "country_name" is an analyzed field which is some thing I can not change`, why can't you change it? do you have read/write access to the cluster?

Comment: other users need the field to keep it's current settings

Comment: you can try it the logstash way, when you use logstash to import data into elasticsearch for every analyzed field like your `country_name` there will be a .raw field like `country_name.raw` which is not analyzed. maybe you can use the same procedure